# Unable to locate package php7.0-phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, apt

I have "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" OS and trying to install phpoffice/phpspreadsheet using command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

Getting error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-phpoffice
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0-phpoffice'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-phpoffice'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing up Composer (as the repository for PHP packages) and the repository for Ubuntu packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension gd is required and i can't find the package in my php7.0 version. The following commands used to install the extension gd.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

Then we can use composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

> Ubuntu » Packages » Package Search Results:
>
> php7.0-phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
>
> Sorry, your search gave no results

.

> PHP Package Repository:
>
> php7.0-phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
>
> PHPSpreadsheet - Read, Create and Write Spreadsheet documents in PHP -
>   Spreadsheet engine

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

Comment: Tried using the above command. 
     **composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet**
It results in:
          - Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.4 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.4.0].
          - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.4.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.